# How can my UWP app authenticate with a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, authentication, win-universal-app, wcf-security, windows-10-universal

I'm writing an UWP app in C#, and I'm trying to have it consume data from a (pre-existing) WCF service. I can't find any information online on the subject. Here is what my code looks like (WCF service is `Serv`, service namespace is `Ns`):

```
var config = Ns.ServClient.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IServ;
var client = new Ns.ServClient(config);
var result = client.TestCall();
```

I get the following exception, which I don't understand how to parse:

> Exception thrown:
>   'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
>   authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received
>   from the server was 'Negotiate, NTLM'.

What does this error message mean? And how do I successfully authenticate with the WCF service?

Bonus question: what is the `ServiceReferences.Designer.ClientConfig` file? How do I use it?

Comment: Could you please try a console client to call the wcf service? And tell the result? And try the solution in this thread:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/779cf325-0008-473b-b99b-affe22678aea/getting-systemservicemodelsecuritymessagesecurityexception-error-but-it-works-why?forum=wcf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened the `Package.appxmanifest` file and added the **Enterprise Authentication** and **Private Networks (Client & Server)** capabilities. This fixed the issue.